# Case/if-else statement to create new column in new csv

Tags: bash, csv

I'm trying to do a case/if-else statement on a CSV file (e.g., `myfile.csv`) that analyzes a column, then creates a new column in a new csv (e.g., `myfile_new.csv`).

The source data (`myfile.csv`) looks like this:

```
unique_id,variable1,variable2
1,,C
2,1,
3,,A
4,,B
5,1,
```

I'm trying to do two transformations:

- For the second field, if the input file has any data in the field, have it be 1, otherwise 0.
- The third field is flattened into three fields. If the input file has an `A` in the third field, the third output field has `1`, and `0` otherwise; the same for `B` and `C` and the fourth/fifth field in the output file.

I want the result (`myfile_new.csv`) to look like this:

```
unique_id,variable1,variable2_A,variable2_B,variable2_C
1,0,0,0,1
2,1,0,0,0
3,0,1,0,0
4,0,0,1,0
5,1,0,0,0
```

I'm trying to do the equivalent of this in `SQL`

```
select unique_id, 
case when len(variable1)>0 then 1 else 0 as variable1, 
case when variable2 = 'A' then 1 else 0 end as variable2_A, 
case when variable2 = 'B' then 1 else 0 end as variable2_B, 
case when variable2 = 'C' then 1 else 0 end as variable2_C, ...
```

I'm open to whatever, but CSV files will be 500GB - 1TB in size so it needs to work with that size file.

Comment: I don't understand where the 4th and 5th column in the output come from and what you mean by "dummy variables".

Comment: Dummy variables mean flattening out a categorical variable to numerical variables. Given the first row has a 'C' for variable2 --> variable2_A is 0, variable2_B is 0, and variable2_C = 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an awk solution that would do it:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    FS = ","
    OFS = ","
}

NR == 1 {
    $3 = "variable2_A"
    $4 = "variable2_B"
    $5 = "variable2_C"
    print
    next
}

{
    $2 = ($2 == "") ? 0 : 1
    $3 = ($3 == "A" ? 1 : 0) "," ($3 == "B" ? 1 : 0) "," ($3 == "C" ? 1 : 0)
    print
}' myfile.csv > myfile_new.csv
```

In the `BEGIN` block, we set input and output file separator to a comma.

The `NR == 1` block creates the header for the output file and skips the third block.

The third block checks if the second field is empty and stores `0` or `1` in it; the `$3` statement concatenates the result of using the ternary operator `?:` three times, comma separated.

The output is

```
unique_id,variable1,variable2_A,variable2_B,variable2_C
1,0,0,0,1
2,1,0,0,0
3,0,1,0,0
4,0,0,1,0
5,1,0,0,0
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty solution using a while loop.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Variables:
line=""
result=""
linearray[0]=0

while read line; do
    unset linearray #Clean the variables from the previous loop
    unset result
    IFS=',' read -r -a linearray <<< "$line" #Splits the line into an array, using the comma as the field seperator
    result="${linearray[0]}""," #column 1, at index 0, is the same in both files.
    if [ -z "${linearray[1]}" ]; then #If column 2, at index 1, is empty, then...
        result="$result""0""," #Pad empty strings with zero
    else #Otherwise...
        result="$result""${linearray[1]}""," #Copy the non-zero column 2 from the old line
    fi
    #The following read index 2, for column 3, and add on the appropriate text. Only one can ever be true.
    if [ "${linearray[2]}" == "A" ]; then result="$result""1,0,0"; fi
    if [ "${linearray[2]}" == "B" ]; then result="$result""0,1,0"; fi
    if [ "${linearray[2]}" == "C" ]; then result="$result""0,0,1"; fi
    if [ "${linearray[2]}" == "" ]; then result="$result""0,0,0"; fi
    echo $result >> myfile_new.csv #append the resulting line to the new file
done <myfile.csv
```